# Android SlidingDrawer how-to

Tags: android, listview, slidingdrawer

I've looked in many places, but I cant find a decent tutorial on how to make a SlidingDrawer for my application.

Say i already have an XML file, and i want to add a sliding drawer to it..i also want to add a textview and listview object, and some buttons in it...how would i go about doing that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [`SlidingDrawer` sample app](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/DrawerDemo/). In particular, here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF4444CC"
        >
    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tray_handle_normal"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="I'm in here!"
        />
    </SlidingDrawer>
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, in this case, the whole activity is just a `SlidingDrawer`. That's relatively unusual -- this sample is short because it is from a book.

More commonly, I would expect you to put a `SlidingDrawer` as a child of a `RelativeLayout`, so you can have other children of the `RelativeLayout` and have the drawer slide over top of them when opened. I believe you will need the `SlidingDrawer` to be the last child of the `RelativeLayout` in this case.